# Android NDK build: File not found Error

Tags: android, android-ndk

Need your guidance, I am writing one app in android with the help of native code which will communicate with CAN (Controller Area Network) port ; for that in my C code i used linux/can.h header file. and i am following "http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/" this link to build my app. but one i set all thing i got bellow msg in eclipse console box

```
Compile thumb : can_port <= cansend.c
jni/cansend.c:14:23: fatal error: linux/can.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/can_port/cansend.o] Error 1
```

One more thing, i am working on windows environment. But i don't think  this may be cause.

Comment: You can simply include `#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif ` in all of your header files in which you're facing this issue.  `__cplusplus` will be defined for any compilation unit that is being run through the C++ compiler. It works really well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that it is not a Windows/Linux problem. The simple problem is that compiler is unable to find the file **can.h**. Now, for your info, when the compiler starts compiling, it searches for its header files in the folder

> C:\(path to NDK folder)\platforms\(android-version)\(arch)\usr\include\linux

Now, if there isn't a **can.h** there, the compiler will flag an error. So the best way is

1. Either copy can.h to the above path (not tested)
2. Modify your Makefile to path to the correct directory where this header file is kept

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Royston, how can i copy only can.h at that location "http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/can.h" i think there will be some dependency.

Comment: Yes, there might be added dependency with can.h as it may depend on some other header files. You will need to resolve them to get your app compiled.

Comment: Is there any way to create custom NDK for it?

Comment: No, you don't need to create another NDK or to add the files from **tomoyo** project to the NDK. You should add the path to the directories where you put the **tomoyo** include files that you use to your `Android.mk`, using `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i am new for NDK, i kept linux folder from that site to ndk's "android-ndk-r8b\platforms\android-3\arch-arm\usr\include" but i changed it's name from linux to linux1 coz there is already one linux folder. now i am including that folder in my code like: #include <linux1/can.h> still i am getting the same error. So is there any other way or i have to make any entry of linux1 folder in my project.